# Display PDF from path saved in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I have the path to a pdf file saved in a mysql database. What I want to do is query the database for that path and then display the pdf. I've tried a few different things but it keeps asking to download the file instead of displaying it. I'm getting confused what the best way to approach this is. I can pull what I need from the database but i can't get the pdf to display properly. I also tried saving it as a blob and then displaying it from the database but I ran into the same problem. If I made the 
header("Content-type: application/pdf"); it prompts me to download but if I take it away I only get the crazy symbols. 
Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
    /*$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT doc FROM tbl_docs WHERE id = 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $content = $row['doc'];
    echo $content;*/

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT path FROM tbl_docs WHERE id = 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $content = $row['path'];
    $handle = fopen($content, 'r');
?>

<img src="<?php echo $handle ?>;" alt="something">
```

Comment: are you serious? to use header() forget the html-tags! and output only the content of your pdf and then die() or exit()

Comment: That's what I was doing but when I use header it asks me to download the file instead of displaying it. I only used the html to see if that changed anything. I'm confused why it asks to download the file.

Comment: you **can't** use header() and echo xxx or other output in one request! take a look at header() and it's content-types to set handle you whish want to have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a **PDF** file is not an image, so it may not be used with the `<img>` element.

Secondly, in your example, `$handle` is a pointer to a file, so, even if `$row['path']` were the URI to an actual image (e.g. JPG or PNG), you would still be unable to use `$handle` that way.

If your file, on the other hand, were a JPG, you could could simply use it as follows

```
<img src="<?php echo $row['path']; ?>">
```

provided that `$row['path']` were publicly available over the Internet (or, at least, available to the client that is trying to load the page).

If, however, your file (e.g. JPG) were not reachable by the web browser, you could "base64 encode" its BLOB and insert it directly as data into the image element, like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo 'data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode(file_get_contents($row['path'])); ?>">
```

Finally, to go back to the PDF file, one way to render it on a web page would be to open it inside an `<iframe>`, like this:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $row['path']; ?>"></iframe>
```

again, provided that `$row['path']` could be reached by the web browser.

I hope this helps! :)